# Font family for specific table using kable() in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a new column type ato align decimal points in each column in the output table using kable. When I create the new column using type the package siunitx like `\newcolumntype{d}{S[table-format=+1.2]}` the font family of my pdf, when I knit the document.

Does anyone have a solution?

I've searched the internet for answers, trying out dcolumn package, triend using fontspec etc.